# how to filter out noise while measuring voltage across H bridge?

Tags: adc, h-bridge

I am using a 3 ohm resistor in series with H bridge driver to detect stall current. When it stalls the current shoots upto 200 mA causing a drop of 0.6 V. I am measuring voltage across the H bridge so, I will sense a voltage of VDD - 0.6, based on which I can decide that the motor is stalled and I can stop driving the motor. My question is will the voltage across the bridge will be very noisy. I am giving the voltage input to ADC of the micro controller directly. Is it manageable in software itself to filter out the noise?

Comment: You may want a smaller sense resistor.  You can of course do filtering in software, but be aware that if the analog bandwidth exceeds the nyquist limit of your sampling rate, your resulting representation and any values deduced from it may be misleading in some cases where you may have high frequency components such as switching transients that could alias pathologically.  Adding some capacitance may reduce the analog bandwidth to that which your sampling can represent.

Comment: @chris I have added a capacitor between VDD and the ADC pin. Value is 100 nF. Why should i go with smaller sense resistor? I will need to detect minute change in voltage ad I go on reducing sense resistor value as voltage across H bridge will not dip more anymore

Comment: Does Vdd stay constant when 200mA is taken or does Vdd also dip?

Comment: @Andy, VDD doesn't dip(am unsure). It is from alkaline battery directly. Duracell AA, 2800 mAH, 1.5 V, two numbers

Comment: How many AA batteries in series

Comment: @Andy Two numbers. 1.5 V each. Hence 3 V max

Comment: Your battery (in total) may have a resistance of 0.3 ohms and this will affect the accuracy of the current measurement. As the batteries fade, that resistance could rise to an ohm and then accuracy is a thing of the past. Why don't you use a much smaller resistor to measure current and do it properly with a differential measurment?

Comment: @Andy Can you please share more info on hooking up differential measurement? I totally agree with resistance value of battery. I can estimate it based on battery voltage but don't want to take chances.

Comment: Here is a chip that does it: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8205.pdf AND http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6103f.pdf - you just have to choose one that can operate down to low ish supply voltages as the batteries fade

Comment: @Andy Thank you for the suggestion. I will reply back with the chosen Circuitry.

Comment: @KumarGR - see the answer I've given - I believe this will be your best choice for accuracy and they are not too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/amplifiers/MAX9934.html) is a high-side, differential, current monitor that can run from a single supply voltage as low as 2.5 volts: -

[image]

Max voltage supply is 3.6 volts so it's reasonably suited for a 3V system.

It has a gain of 25uA / mV and this means if you use a 10k resistor (as shown above) the voltage gain is 250 and the output is ground referenced. This means that if 0.6 volts is regarded as equating to 200mA drawn by the motor, the shunt resistor (Rsense) need only drop 2.4mV at 200mA i.e. it has a resistance of 12 milli ohms.

This is far better than using a 3 ohm resistor because your will extend battery life.

As usual ensure enough filtering is present to counteract spikes etc. upsetting the digitization process.

Comment: I will try searching for similar part. I have to operate down till 2.2 V, and also has to be cost sensitive. Any thing above 0.1$ for 100,000 is a no no.

Comment: Would like to take back my comment on price. It can be upto 0.25$, battery life far more important than price. I will search on same lines

Comment: @Umar did you find a solution to this or did you go with low-side current sensing?

Comment: As of the design was concerned, they needed low cost, low size solution. The precision they used to get by measuring voltage across bridge was sufficient. But, for the future design, they are going with costlier but very low power solution, for which I would study this solution again and consider.

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier to measure on a low side current sense resistor. Like 0.1R and a simplest opamp amplifier. Most importantly, synchronize your ADC to the switching PWM and sample a before the switching occurs, that's a silent way of current sensing.

Comment: That's a good point I can take as an input for my software

Comment: There is another good point, but it's a bit tricky to explain. Please, google "advanced unipolar PWM".